# How to Install pip on Solaris 10?

Tags: python-2.6

I am new to python learning.I need to install pip on python2.6. From pip website, I downloaded "pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl" package but by which command I will install it.

I also tried the following option but not succeeded.

```
bash-3.2# apt install python-pip
apt: invalid flag: install
```

Comment: yes, But does not find the suitable answer. In one post they used this "apt install python-pip" command, but not working for me.

Comment: Well, you should edit your question and add this information. Otherwise people will suggest strategies, you already tried.

Comment: need a "whats my environment" universal tool to see if they have prereqs. I am giving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [OpenCSW](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/py_pip/):

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i py_pip 
/usr/sbin/pkgchk -L CSWpy-pip # list files
```

Don't forget to install python27 as well.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Well, the code intends to "Install pip on Solaris 10", and comes right from OpenCSW doc. About OpenCSW project: https://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/introduction.html

Comment: @jim : that is going far beyond installing pip, pkgadd is the Solaris package installer: [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-7932/6jgp82k2l/index.html)